# Send email via the Mandrill API containing multiple BCC addresses

Tags: mailchimp, mandrill

Is their any way to send email via the Mandrill API which contain multiple BCC address?
[Mandrill API documentation](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html) displays only a single `bcc_address` in their API. So is it not possible send email which contain multiple BCC addresses?

Comment: What have you tryed so far? Show us what doesn't work and someone might be able to help you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yup totally doable! According to the [Mandrill API `send` documentation](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send), you can specify multiple addresses in the `to` field, and mark them as `type` `bcc`.

Here's an example:

```
{
   "to":[
      {
         "email":"recipient.email@example.com",
         "name":"Recipient Name",
         "type":"to"
      },
      {
         "email":"bcc.recipient.email.1@example.com",
         "name":"BCC Recipient Name 1",
         "type":"bcc"
      },
      {
         "email":"bcc.recipient.email.2@example.com",
         "name":"BCC Recipient Name 2",
         "type":"bcc"
      }
   ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Also make sure you're passing the value `"preserve_recipients": true` under the message section.

Comment: Did you tested this really? It seems not working at all. I have tried several time and in the logs its not showing anything.

Comment: I recently tested this and it works. However, I had to set "preserve_recipients":true for it to work like I expected. See the documentation. If you see no activity in the API log, you might want to check you are using the right API key and the right API URL.

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to send an email to multiple users but don't want them to be able to see who you sent the email to, and not being able to "reply all", you can set preserveRecipients to false.

Source: http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21688056-Using-SMTP-Headers-to-customize-your-messages#preserve-recipient-headers-for-group-emails

Answer (score 0):

If you are using transactional emails, you can bcc to only one person at a time

https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/api/messages/send-new-message/